# Print lists that contains second element only

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on counting the length of split sentences, but always get index out of range error when trying to print out lines/lists that has `[1]` within them.

The code:

```
for line in open("testing.txt"):
   strip = line.rstrip()
   words = strip.split(';')
   first = words[0]
   for test in words:
      if words[1] in words:
         print(words)
      else:
         continue
```

The split output of the sample `.txt` file are for example:

```
['"What does Bessie say I have done?" I asked.']
['Be seated somewhere', ' and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."']
['Of farthest Thule', ' and the Atlantic surge']
['Pours in among the stormy Hebrides."']
['"Alright, let's get out of here!" I yelled.']
```

So some sentences only got `[0]` element while the ones with `[1]` are the sentences I am trying to print out (The current `if/else` statement doesn't work).

The expected output (basically any split sentences/lists that has a second element):

```
 ['Be seated somewhere', ' and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."']
 ['Of farthest Thule', ' and the Atlantic surge']
```

Comment: Please update to show the expected output.

Comment: What about `if len(words) == 2`?

Comment: when you do `if words[1] in words` you **are accessing** the second element, **whether it exists or not**... This is why you get the error. You want to check the `len` of the list first, or use a `try/except` block

Comment: "Working on counting the length of split sentences," Did you try putting, for example, `python length of list` into a search engine?

Comment: I try to count the number of words of split sentences (break at semicolon)*

Comment: @PeanutJams - Please ensure you’re also closing the file handle. A better practice is using the `with open(‘file.txt’) as f:` convention.  Otherwise the file may remain open and cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you try to access the second element of an array that contains only 1 string. In this case you want to check the length of the array

```
for line in open("testing.txt"):
   strip = line.rstrip()
   words = strip.split(';')
   for test in words:
      if len(words) > 1:
         print(words)
      else: # this else is not necessary
         continue
```

Edit: If you want to print each sentences containing at least one ';' only once, you don't actually have to use a for loop. One concise way to get the desired output would be this:

```
for line in open("testing.txt"):
    strip = line.rstrip()
    words = strip.split(';')
    if len(words) > 1:
        print(words)
```

Comment: Note: This will also allow lists with three, four, etc. elements. OP’s stated requirement is two.

Comment: That is not what I get from OP's post: "The expected output (basically any split sentences/lists that has a second element):". If it has a second element, it could also have a third and a fourth etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question you only trying to print the words list which has more than one element.

One simple way to do it is:

```py
    for line in open("testing.txt"):
       strip = line.rstrip()
       words = strip.split(';')
       # first = words[0]
       for test in words:
          if len(words) > 1:
             print(words)
```

Here you are just checking if the length of the words is greater than 1 and printing if that is the case

**EDIT:**
I think the for loop is unnecessary. All you want is to print lists of words greater than length 1.
So for that purpose:

```py
    for line in open("testing.txt"):
       strip = line.rstrip()
       words = strip.split(';')
       if len(words) > 1:
          print(words)
```

Here you are just splitting the sentences on `;` and then checking after splitting if the length of the list (named words) is greater than 1; if so you are printing the list named words.

**EDIT2**:
As S3DEV had pointed out that you are opening a file inside for keyword which won't close your file automatically once you are out of for loop. As a result the file pointer remains open until the program stopped completely and it might cause weird issues. The best practice is to use `with` keyword. the with keyword automatically opens the file nad closes it once the block execution is complete, so you won't face any odd issues. form keeping a file pointer open.

```py
    with open("testing.txt", "r") as f: # this line open file as f in read-only format
       for line in f:
          strip = line.rstrip()
          words = strip.split(';')
          if len(words) > 1:
             print(words)
```

Comment: I started posting before there were any answers. Sorry I haven't noticed, but I have modified to add something new @S3DEV

Comment: Recommendation: Improve the previous answer.  How? Suggest, explain and demonstrate the `with open(‘file.txt’) as f:` convention to ensure the file handle is closed automatically after processing.  Otherwise the file handles are remaining open.